# BoxReorderer pluging is not working for table layout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

BoxReorderer pluging is not working for table layout.

I am trying reoder my compnents in extJS panel. for that I am using "Ext.ux.BoxReorderer". but when i am applying this I am getting this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'table')**

Here is my code :

```
var containerObj = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            plugins: Ext.create("Ext.ux.BoxReorderer"),
            style: '{padding:20px}',
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                columns: 4,
                
            },
            defaults: {
                style: {
                    padding : '7px'
                },
                labelAlign : 'top',
                width : '180px'

            },
            items: elementData,
        });
```

Any work around for this. How to do reordering of elemnet in extJS table layout.

Comment: I am not sure it will work with `table` layout. `Ext.ux.BoxReorderer` is basically used for reordering tabs in a panel, and it is probably not prepared for more complex layouts. If you use "one-dimensional" `vbox` or `hbox` layout it works.

Comment: @PeterKoltai yes, for one dimenion it will works fines. anywork around for reodering the element in table layout. Not able to find in net